# \cite not working like it should

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I really need your help. I'm new to LaTeX and on start it worked with `\cite` but when I try now (even with a fresh document), it isn't working like it should. You can see my "fresh test LaTeX file", the bib file and the output below. You guys have any idea? :/

I can choose the book of a suggestion list but then it will output unformatted - just the ID....

Latex Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\bibliography{libary.bib} % with extension
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[style=apa,
backend=biber,
bibencoding=utf8,
language=ngerman,
mincitenames=1,
maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \cite{BadkeSchaub.2008}
\end{document}
```

Bib Code:

```
@book{BadkeSchaub.2008,
 author = {Badke-Schaub, Petra and Hofinger, Gesine and Lauche, Kristina},
 year = {2008},
 title = {Human Factors: Psychologie sicheren Handelns in Risikobranchen},
 url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-72321-9},
 address = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
 publisher = {{Springer Medizin Verlag Heidelberg}},
 isbn = {978-3-540-72321-9},
 doi = {10.1007/978-3-540-72321-9}
}
```

Output:

> BadkeSchaub.2008

Comment: The `\bibliography` comes too early. Remove `\bibliography{libary.bib}` and add `\addbibresource{libary.bib}` *after* you load `biblatex`. You also need to make sure you run Biber (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: oh my god! Thank you mate! You are my lifesaver!

Comment: With the given preamble you don't need the options `bibencoding=utf8, language=ngerman,`. Additionally `style=apa` implements APA style for citations and does not respond to `mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=2` as other styles, so it can probably go.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `biblatex` you need to call `\bibliography` or `\addbibresource` *after* you load `biblatex`. `\bibliography` is also defined by standard LaTeX, but `biblatex` needs to redefine it to work properly, hence it only works properly if it is called after `biblatex` was loaded.

With `biblatex` it is recommended to use `\addbibresource` instead of `\bibliography`. In general `\bibliography` should be used *without* the file extension, `\addbibresource` *with* extension. Depending on your TeX distribution or OS it might work otherwise, but that is not guaranteed.

Your current preamble also makes a few of your `biblatex` options unnecessary, so your document could look like

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{libary.bib} % with extension

\begin{document}
  \cite{BadkeSchaub.2008}
\end{document}
```